# Java: Difference between two dates spanning over months

Tags: java, date, time

I have the following code that successfully gets me the difference between two days (in days, hours, minutes, seconds):

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
Date d1 = format.parse(startTime);
Date d2 = format.parse(endTime);
long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
System.out.println("Start: " + startTime);
System.out.println("End: " + endTime);
System.out.println(diffDays + " days, " + diffHours + " hours, " + diffMinutes + " minutes, " + diffSeconds + " seconds");
```

However, this does not work when the dates cross into another month, for example:

```
Start: 2013-07-31 10:15:01
End: 2013-08-01 11:22:33
-29 days, -22 hours, -52 minutes, -28 seconds

Start: 2013-05-31 10:15:01
End: 2013-08-01 11:22:33
-29 days, -22 hours, -52 minutes, -28 seconds
```

Is it possible to intelligently span over months and get accurate time differences? I am familiar with Joda but would like to stick with standard Java APIs unless this is not possible without something like Joda.

Comment: Well you can reimplement a bunch of the work from Joda Time - it's not magic, after all - but you'd be a *lot* better off just using Joda Time. That said, it's not clear that you need Joda Time in this case - I think you'd just got a broken formatter...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
```

Should be

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

You'll get the correct result of

```
Start: 2013-05-31 10:15:01
End: 2013-08-01 11:22:33
62 days, 1 hours, 7 minutes, 32 seconds
```

[Here's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) the javadoc for the date patterns. `dd` is day in month. `DD` is day in year. Your `Date` objects just weren't parsed the way you expected. Basically the day in year value of `31` was overwriting the month value.

Debuggers are your friend.

Comment: Gosh, I guess I should pay more attention to those Javadocs. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: @Matt Sure thing. In situations like this, it's best to check the values of your Date (or other) objects before using them.

Answer (score 5):

While you should use Joda Time simply as a *much* better date/time API, I suspect the problem is *actually* just that you're parsing the values incorrectly. Use a format string of:

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```

... with `dd` instead of `DD`. The `DD` value is "day in year" which I suspect is confusing things, basically overriding the month part entirely. See the [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) documentation for more details.

You can validate what's wrong by printing out `d1` and `d2` after parsing...

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

In [Java 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later…

```
Duration.between(
    LocalDateTime.parse( "2013-07-31T10:15:01" ) ,
    LocalDateTime.parse( "2013-08-01T11:22:33" )
).getDaysPart()
```

…and…

```
.getHoursPart()
.getMinutesPart()
.getSecondsPart()
```

## java.time

The other Answers are outdated. The Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode, and advises migration to the java.time classes built into Java.

### `Period`

The [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class represents a span of time not attached to the timeline as a total number of seconds and nanoseconds. Such a span can be interpreted as a number of days, hours, minutes, and seconds assuming generic 24-hour days and 60-minute hours as no time zone is included.

```
LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.parse( "2013-07-31T10:15:01" );
LocalDateTime stop = LocalDateTime.parse( "2013-08-01T11:22:33" );
Duration d = Duration.between( start , stop );
```

> span: 2013-07-31T10:15:01/2013-08-01T11:22:33
>
> d.toString(): PT25H7M32S

These strings are in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. The `PT25H7M32S` string uses a format of [`PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) where `P` marks the beginning and the `T` separates the years-months-days from hours-minutes-seconds. The string `PT25H7M32S` means “twenty-five hours, seven minutes, and thirty-two seconds”.

See that [code live in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/WOhq15).

In Java 9 and later (but not Java 8), these `Duration` methods extract each part.

Given a duration of 49H30M20.123S…

- `toDaysPart()` = 2
- `toHoursPart()` = 1
- `toMinutesPart()` = 30
- `toSecondsPart()` = 20
- `toMillisPart()` = 123
- `toNanosPart()` = 123000000

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look at joda-time library http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Java default implementation of dates kind of suck, using joda time you can compute the intervals you want and its compatible with java Date class.

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/quickstart.html (look at interval and time periods)