# Difference between dates to get "time ago"

Tags: java, date, time

I have one date. wanna compare it with current date and wants the results in time ago.

```
Date d1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-dd").parse((String) request.
            getParameter(date1));
Date d2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-dd").parse((String) request.
            getParameter(date2));

long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
```

and want this difference in time ago format.

eg. 3 hours 2 mins ago

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18256451/java-difference-between-two-dates-spanning-over-months?rq=1 may contain the answer you want.

Comment: @SimplyPanda No, not that.

Comment: Certainly contains a direction to go toward, at least.

Answer (score 2):

If using another library is possible for you, I would recommend [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), especially that [JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) it will be introduced in the JDK 8 as the new Date API, being Joda time re arhitected.

Time difference with Joda Time [here](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/faq.html#datediff).

Comment: Actually, [JSR 310: Date and Time API](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) is included with Java 8. Inspired by Joda-Time, but re-architected.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to use core Java and not pollute your code with numeric literals:

```
long diffInMillis = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
long diffInHours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(diffInMillis);
long diffInMins = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(diffInMillis);
System.out.printf("%d hours %d mins ago%n", diffInHours, (diffInMins - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(diffInHours)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have long value which are milli seconds, so

```
int min= (int) ((diff / (1000*60)) % 60);
int sec= (int) (diff / 1000) % 60 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
 long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
 long m= diff/(60*1000);
 long hour=m/60;
 long minutes=m%60;

 System.out.printf("%d hours %d mins ago%n", hour, minutes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is another way to get as per your requirement but `getHours()` and `getMinutes()` is deprecated
simply do `System.out.println((d2.getHours()-d1.getHours())+" hours " +(d2.getMinutes()-d2.getMinutes()) +" mins ago"`);

Answer (score 0):

friends.i think we can do this,my code:

```
public static String getIntervalUpdateTime(long intervalTime) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    long interval = intervalTime / 1000;
    final long day = 24 * 60 * 60;
    final long hour = 60 * 60;
    final long minute = 60;
    int detailDay = 0;
    int detailHour = 0;
    int detailMinute = 0;
    int detailSecond = 0;
    if (interval >= day) {
        detailDay = (int) (interval / day);
        interval = interval - detailDay * day;
    }
    if (interval >= hour) {
        detailHour = (int) (interval / hour);
        interval = interval - hour * detailHour;
    }
    if (interval >= minute) {
        detailMinute = (int) (interval / minute);
        interval = interval - detailMinute * minute;
    }
    if (interval > 0) {
        detailSecond = (int) interval;
    }
    result.setLength(0);
    if (detailDay > 0) {
        result.append(detailDay);
        result.append("day");
    }
    if (detailHour > 0) {
        result.append(detailHour);
        result.append("hour");
    }
    if (detailMinute > 0) {
        result.append(detailMinute);
        result.append("minutes");
    }
    if (detailSecond > 0) {
        result.append(detailSecond);
        result.append("seconds");
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

---

this is my answer.

Comment: call this method,param is diff. you will get answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Period](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_period.html) class in [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3, built just for this purpose.

See example code in answers (especially [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2179831/642706)) to the question, [How to calculate elapsed time from now with Joda-Time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2179644/642706).