# Java 8: Calculate difference between two ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, date, datetime, java-8, timezone

I'm trying to write a method to print the time difference between two **ZonedDateTime**s, regarding the difference between time zones.

I found some solutions but all of them were written to work with **LocalDateTime**.

Comment: Post a concrete example of what you want to achieve, and get as a result.

Comment: Michał's answer is exactly what I expected. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 170, accepted):

You can use method *between* from [**ChronoUnit**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html).

This method converts those times to same zone (zone from the first argument) and after that, invokes *until* method declared in **Temporal** interface:

```
static long zonedDateTimeDifference(ZonedDateTime d1, ZonedDateTime d2, ChronoUnit unit){
    return unit.between(d1, d2);
}
```

Since both **ZonedDateTime** and **LocalDateTime** implements **Temporal** interface, you can write also universal method for those date-time types:

```
static long dateTimeDifference(Temporal d1, Temporal d2, ChronoUnit unit){
    return unit.between(d1, d2);
}
```

But keep in mind, that invoking this method for mixed **LocalDateTime** and **ZonedDateTime** leads to **DateTimeException**.

Comment: Is there a way to get the difference between two ZDT types where the ZoneId is different between the two ZDT's?

Comment: @stanlick Yes: `Duration.between( zdtA , zdtB )` as shown in [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41081733/642706). I imagine the `between` method is simply calling `ZonedDateTime::toInstant()` on both.

Answer (score 115):

## tl;dr

For hours, minutes, seconds:

```
Duration.between( zdtA , zdtB )  // Represent a span-of-time in terms of days (24-hour chunks of time, not calendar days), hours, minutes, seconds. Internally, a count of whole seconds plus a fractional second (nanoseconds).
```

For years, months, days:

```
Period.between(                  // Represent a span-of-time in terms of years-months-days. 
    zdtA.toLocalDate() ,         // Extract the date-only from the date-time-zone object. 
    zdtB.toLocalDate() 
)
```

## Details

The [Answer by Michal S](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41077151/642706) is correct, showing [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html).

## `Duration` & `Period`

Another route is the [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) and [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) classes. Use the first for shorter spans of time (hours, minutes, seconds), the second for longer (years, months, days).

```
Duration d = Duration.between( zdtA , zdtB );
```

Produce a String in [standard ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) by calling `toString`. The format is `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS` where the `P` marks the beginning and `T` separates the two portions.

```
String output = d.toString();
```

In Java 9 and later, call the `to…Part` methods to get the individual components. Discussed in [another Answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40620807/642706).

### Example code

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdtStart = ZonedDateTime.now( z );
ZonedDateTime zdtStop = zdtStart.plusHours( 3 ).plusMinutes( 7 );

Duration d = Duration.between( zdtStart , zdtStop );
```

> 2016-12-11T03:07:50.639-05:00[America/Montreal]/2016-12-11T06:14:50.639-05:00[America/Montreal]
>
> PT3H7M

See [live code in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/5OCaOe).

## `Interval` & `LocalDateRange`

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project adds functionality to the java.time classes. One of its handy classes is [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html) to represent a span of time as a pair of points on the timeline. Another is [`LocalDateRange`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html), for a pair of [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) objects.  In contrast, the `Period` & `Duration` classes each represent a span of time as *not* attached to the timeline.

The factory method for `Interval` takes a pair of `Instant` objects.

```
Interval interval = Interval.of( zdtStart.toInstant() , zdtStop.toInstant() );
```

You can obtain a `Duration` from an `Interval`.

```
Duration d = interval.toDuration();
```

---

[image: Table of span-of-time classes in Java and in the ThreeTen-Extra project]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Where are you seeing an `of` method on Duration that takes two instants? I only see `public static Duration of(long amount, TemporalUnit unit)`

Comment: @BrianGordon Fixed, replacing `.of` with `.between`. Thanks.

Comment: Duration works with ZonedDateTime meanwhile Period works with LocalDate. a call to the method toLocalDate() needs to be done on our zdt object.

Comment: @guillaumeguerin You are correct. Fixed my code example. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This gives you minutes between two ZonedDateTimes.

```java
int minutes = (int) (end.toEpochSecond() - start.toEpochSecond()) / 60;
```

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. Sorry, it’s not the recommended way, and in special cases it will give completely wrong results.